# Elementary OS won't shut down

Tags: release-juno

i downloaded the lastest version of elementary os, after i install it and use for many hours i tried to shut dowm, but i didn't work. I tried a lot of time, but nothing happens.

i'm using the OS 5 Juno.

Anyone knows how to help me?

thanks.

Comment: What happens when you execute `sudo shutdown` command in Terminal?

Comment: Did you installed on laptop or Desktop, if is on laptopd do you have a TLP installed?